# Django/App-Engine: Getting HTML error response when doing HTTP POST request (HTTP GET works)

Tags: django, json, google-app-engine, httprequest

If I do a `nc 192.168.2.10 8080` and then `GET /test/` I get as expected a JSON response:

```
Content-Type: text/javascript
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 74

{ ... a JSON message ...}
```

However, if I do a `POST /test/` I get the following HTML doc as a result:

```
<head>
<title>Error response</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Error response</h1>
<p>Error code 400.
<p>Message: Bad HTTP/0.9 request type ('POST').
<p>Error code explanation: 400 = Bad request syntax or unsupported method.
</body>
```

Anyone an idea where the problem could be?

Comment: It sounds like you're not properly forming your request to the server. Use wget or curl so you can test it without it relying on your knowledge of HTTP syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nick Johnson said in his comment, try a tool that forms requests properly for you.

Another common source of these sorts of errors is trying to parse a GET request on the server (for arguments or whatever) while you're getting  a post request.

Also something that always gets me, but that's a 403, is csrf protection. Remember to turn it off for requests you want to make via curl and similar :)